# controller on a typescript angular directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, typescript, angularjs-controller

Binding seems to be not working when a controller written in typescript and called by the directive. **this is the directive**

```
import controller = require('framework/frameworkController');

export class FrameworkDirective implements ng.IDirective {
 static instance(): ng.IDirective {
     return new FrameworkDirective;
 }
 controller = 'frameworkController';
 scope: any = {
    title: '@',
 };
  templateUrl = "controlslibrary/framework/frameworkTemplate.html"
}
```

**this is the controller**

```
 export class FrameworkController implements IFrameworkController {
      public isMenuButtonVisible: boolean = true;
      constructor(public $rootScope: ng.IRootScopeService, public $window: ng.IWindowService){
              var fc = this;
            $($window).on('resize.framework', () => {
                   $rootScope.$apply(() => {
                   fc.checkWidth();
                    });
            });
      }

      public checkWidth() {
           var width = Math.max($(this.$window).width(), this.$window.innerWidth);
           this.isMenuButtonVisible = !(width < 768);
      }
 }
```

**this is the template url**

```
 <div ng-if="isMenuButtonVisible">
      <button type="button" class="btn nav-button">
              <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
      </button>
 </div>
```

**finally this is my module**

```
  import controller = require('framework/frameworkController');
  import directive = require('framework/frameworkDirective');

  angular.module("framework", ['ui.router'])
   .controller("frameworkController", controller.FrameworkController)
   .directive("framework", directive.FrameworkDirective.instance);
```

when the window is resized it has to check and bring up the button. I can step through the code and it throws no error but the binding is broken. what am i doing wrong?

Comment: I would change the controller to inject $scope, then use $scope.$on('resize.framework',()=>{...code...}). Not sure if that will work, but I would test it as a starting point. Would you have your code in a gist so that I could fiddle with it?

Comment: resize.framework fires and works just fine, It is the binding that is not working. Should I use $scope to binding to view for controllers, just for directives? the code is in my office network, gist is not allowed.

Comment: It seems like there is no "isMenuButtonVisible" on the scope of the directive itself. I am not sure if the following will work as I have never tried it this way before: Have you tried adding a link function to the directive to get access to the controller in the directive:

    `link = (scope, element: ng.IAugmentedJQuery, attrs: any, controller: controller.FrameworkController) => {
        scope.isMenuButtonVisible = controller.isMenuButtonVisible;
    }`

Comment: You sure `return new FrameworkDirective;` does not give you syntax error?

Comment: Maybe injecting `$scope` in the controller and using `$scope.$apply` instead of `$rootScope.$apply` (not sure though). Also, put a break in your code inside checkWidth method. I think `this` might be referring to the window and not the controller, and hence the properties might not be what you think.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the comments. I had to include isMenuButtonVisible as a property to $scope to make it work. it wouldn't bind unless it is a part of $scope.

```
 interface IFrameworkControllerScope extends ng.IScope {
       isMenuVisible: boolean;
 }

 export class FrameworkController 
 {
   $scope.isMenuButtonVisible = true;
   constructor({public $scope : IFrameworkControllerScope,  public $window: ng.IWindowService){

   $($window).on('resize.framework', () => {
        $scope.$apply(() => {
            checkWidth();
        });
    });

   var checkWidth = () =>{
        var width = Math.max($(this.$window).width(), this.$window.innerWidth);
        $scope.isMenuButtonVisible = !$scope.isMenuVisible;
    }
 }
```